# EF Code first Error when try to add relation between Asp.net Identity ApplicationUsers table and Another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add relation between ApplicationUsers table and table i added name UserType, And after adding a migration i got this error:

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.UserTypes_UserTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "TestDB", table "dbo.UserTypes", column 'Id'.

My Code:

```
 public class UserType
{
    public UserType()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name="Acount Type")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
public UserType UserType { get; set; }
```

to this

```
public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
```